# QuickTime API fails with error 2048

Tags: c++, macos, video, quicktime, openframeworks

I have trouble with QuickTime API on MacOS 10.7.2(b.11C74).

Here is a piece of [openFrameworks](http://openframeworks.cc) code which opens a movie descriptor:

```cpp
// ofQuickTimePlayer.cpp
bool createMovieFromURL(string urlIn,  Movie &movie){
    char * url = (char *)urlIn.c_str();
    Handle urlDataRef;
    OSErr err;
    urlDataRef = NewHandle(strlen(url) + 1);
    // ...
    BlockMoveData(url, *urlDataRef, strlen(url) + 1);
    err = NewMovieFromDataRef(
        &movie, 
        newMovieActive, 
        nil, 
        urlDataRef, 
        URLDataHandlerSubType);
    // ...
    if ( err != noErr ) {
       ofLog(OF_LOG_ERROR,"createMovieFromURL: error loading url");
       return false;
    } else {
       return true;
    }
}
```

All I need is just to open HLS video stream.

Testing the Apple HLS stream doesn't fail to load but no video is rendered. 
Here it is: http://devimages.apple.com/iphone/samples/bipbop/bipbopall.m3u8

My test HLS stream fails to load and err equals `-2048` in this case.

Everything works perfectly with .mp4 transferred by HTTP and with RTSP protocol.

Same streams play perfectly in QuickTime Player 10.1 (501.5).

Details of my tiny research are here: https://github.com/openframeworks/openFrameworks/issues/897

So my questions are:

1. What is the cause of this strange behavior?
2. How to fix it?

Comment: this is all i got. hopefully this helps. :-/ http://www.moviecodec.com/solutions/quicktime-error-2048-fix-41979/

Comment: Did michaelcurry suggestion help? If not, what does that error return mean?

Comment: @JohnOdom Haven't tried this solution with OpenFrameworks on 10.7. The only thing I can say is that native ObjC code works fine with HLS streams using QuickTime framework on my MacOS 10.9.